# Android: i need to navigate to a same activity through different activities and returning back to those activities after im finished

Tags: android

I have two activities one is saved address activity and the other is a cart activity both have a button to navigate to the same page which is map to get the location and after finding the location their redirected to another page which is to fill  their house no and after filling them it has a button when clicked I want an event to get back to their starting activities

I used intent extras to put information as key values 1 and 2 in the corresponding pages and checked it at the end but still no use

Comment: Please show us the code

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you want to send the information (location, house no) back to your starting activity?

One "dirty" solution would be like:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(mContext, YourDestinationActivity.class);
  mIntent.putExtra("location", location);
  mIntent.putExtra("houseNo", houseNo);
  startActivity(mIntent);
```

But for this kind of workflow I would use [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

Comment: No sir i actually want to open two different pages when the same buttton is clicked depending upon the activites they started with

Comment: actually intent.setflags and getflags worked for me it told my other activity from which is my previous activity